# can anyone help me in using "git svn clone https://svnrepo/svnpath" in Perl script?

Tags: git, perl, shell, svn

If I include the command as `git svn clone https://svnrepo/svnpath` in my script, the error I get is:

W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: /svnpath path not found

While the command works fine when run on a terminal, but doesn't execute when called from the perl script.

Comment: Can you provide some details about what you are doing?  Are you calling "system(git clone..)" or are you using the perl GIT::* modules? which one? provide examples of what doesn't work please.

Comment: I'm using `git svn clone https://SVNRepo/SvnPath` within the "`" in Perl program. I'm not using the perl GIT::* module.

Comment: In my limited testing, I found system("/usr/bin/git ....") did what I wanted.  It failed when I didn't use the full path to git, which doesn't quite make sense.  The error was from git, which means it was able to launch git, which then couldn't find the SVN module. I suspect the environment inside the perl system() call (or backticks) is different than what you expect.  Consider checking for proxy settings which might be in your environment and are affecting the https:// request.

Answer (score 0):

Try to embed following in your code `system('git svn clone "https://svnrepo/svnpath"');`. If this is what you already have, you'll have to provide more details.`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd try to narrow down the problems...

You say `git svn clone` works from the terminal but not from the program.  Are you running the program from that terminal?  Or is it running from a web server?  The web server would have a completely different environment and permissions.

I'd make sure the URL I'm passing into `git svn clone $url` is what I think it is.  Try hard coding it, or printing `$url` to confirm.

Then I'd try accessing the URL via some other means.  `curl $url` or `wget $url` or using [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple).  If that doesn't work then it's a general networking problem, maybe proxies.

I'd make sure `$ENV{PATH}` is the same in the program as `$PATH` is in my shell.  I'd make sure `which git` reports the same in the program and out.  I'd try hard coding it just in case.

I'd run `git svn help` in the program to make sure it has SVN capabilities.